# How can I run Cassandra on a CoreOS virtual machine?

Tags: docker, cassandra, coreos

I'm trying to install Cassandra on a CoreOS virtual machine. I have read that before launching the Cassandra docker container, I have to start the Cassandra service on CoreOS, through a Cassandra.service file located in /etc/systemd/system folder of the virtual machine.

I have tried the following configuration for the Cassandra.service file

```
[Unit]
Description=cassandra 
After=docker.service 
Requires=docker.service

[Service]
Environment=CASSANDRA_CLUSTERNAME=cluster
CASSANDRA_SSL_STORAGE_PORT=7002 
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/environment
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker kill %p-%i
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker rm %p-%i
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/docker pull endocode/%p
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/bash -c "echo $${COREOS_PUBLIC_IPV4:-$$(hostname - i)} | /usr/bin/etcdctl set /cassandra_%i"
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/bash -c "while [[ ! $$(/usr/bin/etcdctl get /cassandra_1) ]]; do echo 'Waiting for Cassandra Seed node'; sleep 1; done; echo 'Cassandra Seed node is UP'; /usr/bin/etcdctl get /cassandra_1"
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c "BROADCAST_ADDR=$${COREOS_PUBLIC_IPV4:- $$(hostname -i)} && CASSANDRA_SEEDS=$(/usr/bin/etcdctl get /cassandra_1 | /usr/bin/tr -d '\n') && exec /usr/bin/docker run --rm --name %p-%i
-e CASSANDRA_CLUSTERNAME=${CASSANDRA_CLUSTERNAME}
-e CASSANDRA_SEEDS=\"$CASSANDRA_SEEDS\"
-e BROADCAST_ADDR=$BROADCAST_ADDR
-e CASSANDRA_SSL_STORAGE_PORT=$CASSANDRA_SSL_STORAGE_PORT --publish 7000:7000 --publish 
$CASSANDRA_SSL_STORAGE_PORT:$CASSANDRA_SSL_STORAGE_PORT -- publish 9160:9160 --publish 9042:9042 --publish 7199:7199 endocode/%p" 
ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop %p-%i
ExecStopPost=/usr/bin/etcdctl rm /cassandra_%i
TimeoutStartSec=900s

[X-Fleet] 
Conflicts=%p@*.service
```

But when I execute

> sudo systemctl enable Cassandra.service

or

> sudo systemctl start Cassandra.service

I get a **bad unit file setting result** that no gives any useful information.

I was wondering what is wrong in my configuration or if there is any one simplier that could work.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you run the `systemctl daemon-reload`?

Comment: Yes, but the result when I try to run Cassandra.service doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

The "%i" special variable may refer to a template unit, so you have to say "cassandra@1".

Comment: Where I have to say "cassandra@1"? I have tried the previous command `sudo systemctl enable Cassandra@1.service` instead of only Cassandra and still doesn't work. The output now is **invalid argument**.